# Why are mixed-case filenames returned when using bash set construct wildcard?

Tags: bash

I set up a few files to understand bash's set construct wildcard, i.e. [].

```
ls *
1  2  A  bob  darlene  dave  ed  frank  fred  LS_example.sh  Z
```

The files I expected to be returned by `ls [a-z]*` would only include the ones beginning with a lower-case letter, but in the following, files beginning with an upper-case letter are also returned:

```
ls [a-z]*
A  bob  darlene  dave  ed  frank  fred  LS_example.sh
```

Can you explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your locale (and the way it's defined in your OS), `[a-z]` includes the upper and lower case letters. If you want to reliably match lowercase letters, do this:

```
ls [[:lower:]]*
```